# AutoFill credentials without saving in Firefox

Tags: php, forms, firefox, curl, webforms

I run a support service, where users login on https://dashboard.zopim.com/

I need the users to use Firefox only (since I also run some greasemonkey scripts on it), so for this purpose i need to prepopulate the login fields (user and password) without the user being able to see them in cleartext, since then they could jump to chrome, login and use Zopim without my greasemonkey script.

How could i log them in automatically?

1. My first idea was to use CURL in a page on my site, and when they
   visit that the page, it would redirect them to
   https://dashboard.zopim.com/ where a POST request would be sent by
   the script - this does not work.
2. My 2nd idea was to use a password manager addon but all do show in
   cleartext the password to the user - any ideas?
3. My 3rd idea was to lock the Firefox options (actually css hide them)
   but is a kinda silly way.

Any ideas are greately appreciated.

Comment: Requiring users to use a particular browser- that's a fail

Comment: the users are my employees.